# Find content of the tag <Caption>

Tags: regex, xml, caption, innertext

I want to record a macro for Notepad++ to find several Texts which are inside a xml-document with some -tags and a lot of other XML-Tags. So I want to use regex and need a little of help. I think I'm quite close.

example: `<Caption>ThetextIwanttofind</Caption>`

my regex: `<Caption\b[^>]*>(.*?)</Caption>`

The problem is the closing Caption-tag. How to rewrite my regex to get the inner text with the closing Caption?

Thx for your help!

`<Caption\b[^>]*>(.*?)<Caption>` --> works for Caption without a closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use :

```
<Caption\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/?Caption>
                       ^
```

But it's kind of ugly

Comment: Hi Thomas, thx for the fast edit and answer. I tried the regex on [http://regex101.com], but It is not working, maybe because it's "ugly" and not valid?

Comment: @user2766124 you need to escape the `/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/H06r4p/1)

Comment: Ahhh, okay, got it. Thank you so much - YMMD!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you :) @user2766124